can I teach ghidra ARM's MSRs?
I have this instruction in the code:
00 cc 38 d5 mrs x0,sreg(0x3, 0x0, c0xc, c0xc, 0x0)
putting the bytecode into disassmbler, I get: mrs x0, icc_iar1_el1
so ghidra does not recognize this icc_iar1_el1 register. is it possible to teach it?
Note that other registers, such as tpidr_el0 for example, are recognized without any problem.
thanks.
